# validate models.CharField if models.BooleanField is ticked in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Being a Django newbie, I have a question to ask, which should be very simple, but I just can't figure it out:

I have created a model like the one below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_case_id(value):
    if value != "testing":
        raise ValidationError("type testing")

class case_form3_tb(models.Model):
    case_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Case ID", validators=[validate_case_id])
    wound_others = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Others")
    wound_others_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Others (Description)")
```

I want to validate it in a way that if `wound_others` is ticked, then `wound_others_desc` must not be blank.

I just learn how to validate one single text field, but what if the text field is validated based on some other fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need `null=True` for a `CharField`. If you have `blank=True`, the Django admin will save empty strings anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [validate at the model level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), i.e., write a `clean()` method for the model:

```
def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    if self.wound_others and not self.wound_others_desc:
        raise ValidationError('Description must not be blank.')
```

As a side note, the model name you chose is heavily anti-pythonic. You should always follow the [CapWords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) convention for Python class names.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but the Django admin will save `''` instead of `None` for an empty `CharField`. The check should be `if self.wound_others and not self.wound_others_desc`.